# Select correct data when DB has complex PK table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Recipe database. But wee need to look at just 3 tables:

```
[Recipe]
ID (PK)
Name
<...>


[RecipeIngredient]
IDRecipe
IDIngred
Quantity
(IDRecipe, IDIngred) - PK

[Ingredient]
ID (PK)
Name
Units
```

So I want to get table for a certain Recipe name that looks like

```
[Name]    [Quantity]    [Units]
ingr1        50           gr.
ingr2        100          ml.
ingr3        1            kg.
```

My query is

```
SELECT [Name], [Quantity], [Units] FROM [Ingredient], [RecipeIngredient] 
WHERE [ID] = ANY
    (SELECT [IDIngred] FROM [RecipeIngredient] WHERE [IDRecipe] = 
    (SELECT [ID] FROM [Recipe] WHERE [Name] = 'RecipeName1'));
```

But what I get is

```
[Name]    [Quantity]    [Units]
ingr1        50           gr.
ingr1        100          ml.
ingr1        1            kg.
ingr2        50           gr.
ingr2        100          ml.
ingr2        1            kg.
ingr3        50           gr.
ingr3        100          ml.
ingr3        1            kg.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  And *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT I.[Name], RI.[Quantity], I.[Units] 
    FROM [RecipeIngredient] AS RI
        LEFT JOIN [Recipe] AS R ON R.ID = RI.IDRecipe
        LEFT JOIN [Ingredient] AS I ON I.ID = RI.IDIngred
    WHERE R.Name = 'someRecipeName'
```

Comment: Holy Jesus! That works just as I wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT Rec.Name, Ing.Name, Quantity, Units 
FROM Ingredient Ing
Inner Join RecipeIngredient Ri
on Ri.IDIngred  = Ing.ID
Inner Join Recipe Rec
on Rec.ID = Ri.IDRecipe
WHERE Rec.ID IN
            (Select distinct ID from Recipe);
```

The above query returns the name of particular recipe and details of ingredients for that particular recipe, one-by-one.

Hope it helps!